# how to pass the value of a variable that is created in the class A in class B

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent, android-widget

I need to pass the value of a variable That Is created in a class A to a class B. I'm still a beginner and I can not figure out how to proceed. Could you give me a hand?

Comment: paste the code you use to start Activity B.  I am assuming you are using an intent-- so please post that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see below 2 options for passing a String value: through the constructor and through a public setter method.

```
class A {
  void method() {
    String s = "test";
    B b = new B(s);
    b.setValue(s);
  }
}

class B {
  private String value;

  B(String val) {
    value = val;
  }

  public void setValue(String val) {
    value = val;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

to pass any data from one page to other just put these lines of code this will pass your data from one class to the other class.

```
Intent itemintent = new Intent(this, ShowDescription.class);
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putString("feed_type","Your Value");
            itemintent.putExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT", b);

            startActivity(itemintent);
```

this code will call the ShowDescription class pass the data in "feed_type" variable.
and can get data in the showDescription class by th efollowing LOC

```
Bundle b = startingIntent.getBundleExtra("android.intent.extra.INTENT");
b.getString("feed_type")
```

for more can see the following links.
http://grabcodes.blogspot.in/2012/08/passing-data-between-two-activities.html

Answer (score 0):

Pass the value in the Constructor of class B.
 if your both class extends Activity then use intent to pass the data from one Activity to another Activity like this

```
   Intent mIntent = new Intent (classA.this,yourpackage_name.ClassB.class);
   mIntent.putExtra("YourData",variable_holdding_data);
   startActivity(mIntent);
```

and on activityB oncreatmethod(), you can get it like

```
         Intent myIntent = new Intent();
          myIntent= getIntent();
          YourData=myIntent7.getStringExtra("YourData");
```